# Best way to convert two single WordPress sites into Multisite network with shared user base

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

I have two WordPress sites, One is ecommerce site with WooCommerce and other is private login only site for customers of the ecommerce site.

Now I am looking for a way to convert them into a multisite installation with same user base across both sites.

It will great if someone show me a way to achieve that without losing any data from the both sites.

Answer (score -1):

To me the best way would be to:

1. Leave the ecommerce site intact since it's where all the important content exist.
2. Enable multisite on ecommerce site. See official documentation:
   https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
3. Export everything on the private site (Tools - Export - All content)
4. Import it on a new site created on the new network.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. At least post a better method if you are gonna downvote.